# Celery worker with Redis broker can't execute Django task

Tags: redis, celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

I'm learning Python(2.7)/Django(1.5) these days via developing my own Reddit clone (on ubuntu 14.04 LTS). I'm trying to incorporate Celery(3.1) with Redis into the mix, using it to periodically run a ranking algo as a task (on my *local* set up). But unfortunately, I can't get this simple task to execute even once! Can you help me spot what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's my **directory structure**:

```
-unconnectedreddit (manage.py is here)
    -links (tasks.py, models.py, views.py, admin.py)
    -unconnectedreddit (celery.py, __init.py___, settings.py, urls.py)
        -static
        -templates
```

**Celery.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'unconnectedreddit.settings')

app = Celery('unconnectedreddit', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0',include=['unconnectedreddit.links.tasks'])
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS) 

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Additions to **settings.py** are as follows. Note that I did run `migrate` after adding 'djcelery' to installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ('djcelery',)

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('links.tasks', )  

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT=True

from datetime import timedelta

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'rank_all-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.rank_all',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

**__init__.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app1
```

**tasks.py**:

```
import os
from unconnectedreddit import celery_app1
import time
from links.models import Link

@celery_app1.task
def rank_all():
    for link in Link.with_votes.all():
        link.set_rank() #ranks interesting 'links' submitted by users
```

I'm running this command on the Terminal to start a worker: `celery -A unconnectedreddit worker -l info`

The **output** I get is as follows:

```
 -------------- celery@has-VirtualBox v3.1.18 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-3.16.0-30-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         unconnectedreddit:0x7f938b838910
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . links.tasks.rank_all

[2015-06-04 12:01:17,083: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2015-06-04 12:01:17,098: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2015-06-04 12:01:18,107: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
/home/has/.virtualenvs/unconnectedreddit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2015-06-04 12:01:18,136: WARNING/MainProcess] /home/has/.virtualenvs/unconnectedreddit/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py:265: UserWarning: Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments!
  warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '

[2015-06-04 12:01:18,137: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@has-VirtualBox ready.
```

That's it. I had set out to periodically run this task after every 30 seconds (see my CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE). But my code doesn't result in it executing even once - rankings on my reddit clone don't change at all. Can any expert point out what I'm missing in this set up?

Comment: Did you start celery beat? Like `celery -A unconnectedreddit worker -l info -B` or from a separate command like `celery -A unconnectedreddit beat`. Btw I suggest to update to django 1.8 unless you have a really good reason to stick with 1.5.

Comment: @qwattash Trying your suggestion, I get the error: `[2015-06-05 02:10:34,890: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'tasks.rank_all'.` I'm not sure why that can come - I feel I've done everything (as shown in my modules up there).

Comment: I use 1.5 because I'm developing web apps for people in low-resource environments (for Facebook's internet.org). Our projects don't even support JS, for example. Django 1.5 is sufficient for what I'm trying to do here (esp with django-comments built in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrong task name**. This got fixed by changing the task decorator to `@celery_app1.task(name='tasks.rank_all')` and tweaking my beat schedule to include the correct name:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'tasks.rank_all': {
        'task': 'tasks.rank_all',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=30),
    },
}
```